# Copy value of Excel cell relative to certain value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-tables

I have an excel file that contains a list of about 1500 names that have their zip code and I need a way to quickly insert the county relative to this zip.

I have another list that contains the counties based on the ZIP. What is the quickest way to add the correct county value to each person? I have tried to use structured references to do this but have hit a wall.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCSd5.jpg

Comment: Can you share any code of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

seems like an obvious vlookup, unless misreading this question...assuming "James" is A2, in C2 write the following

=vlookup(B2,'Sheet with Counties based on Zip'!A:D,4,false)